# Will sleeping in my car damage it in any way?

Tags: idle, interior

Is it dangerous to take a nap in a car, while leaving the engine idling? I've heard that parking garages are a bad idea, but I assume that being outside gives it area to dissipate.

I will be sleeping for several hours, so is it bad to let the engine idle for this amount of time, for heating etc?

What about with the engine off, will the humidity increase and cause damp etc?

Comment: The problem with questions like this is that it might be safe almost all of the time with no problems, but if you do hit the edge case, and the stars align properly, you're going to die.  And that's only if your concern is limited to Carbon Monoxide.  Robbers might be a bigger threat.

Comment: i thought he meant JUST because of robbers... Napping in a turned on vehicle is never a good idea monoxide or not

Comment: I'm not too worried about robbers. I am just curious because I have to sit around my university for about an hour every morning since I get there early after dropping my wife off. I can park by the open wall of a parking deck, or in my normal spot outside of my building. We have good campus security. I'm more concerned about carbon monoxide

Comment: Edited the question to make it on topic.

Comment: The question isn't about "damaging the car", though.

Comment: Maybe a restating to ask about the risks of long term idling? You see semi-trucks do this at rest stops in the US quite a bit. Is there any harm in doing this to a car?

Answer (score 2):

It is okay to sleep in a car as long as the weather permits, I have done that a couple times myself once in a rest area and other in a Walmart. I was travelling from Minneapolis to Washington DC but the weather was great, I had a comforter and a sleeping bag and slept in the rear seat, but at walmart, you will have to contact the staff and take permission from them (some Walmart's do not allow you to sleep in their parking lots, but there are only 20% that do not allow you to sleep in your car).

Precaution to take:

1. At a rest area, you will have to make sure that there are people in trucks and are parking for the night ( Truckers are good guys).
2. If you want to run your car roll all the windows down a little bit, but what are you gonna get out of it, if you are burning fuel, better find a cheap motel.
3. If at a Walmart make sure you are below a light post or as close as possible to the store's entrance.
4. Make sure the space is properly ventilated and lock your car, though your are inside the car.
5. Stay in well lit areas.

Here are some links that might help you:

Walmart parking lots where you cannot park: http://www.allstays.com/c/walmart-locations-noparking.htm
Another one:
http://www.walmartlocator.com/no-park-walmarts/

A Guide to Car-Camping – in Walmart Parking Lots: http://themorningfresh.com/2012/06/29/a-guide-to-car-camping-in-walmart-parking-lots/

There are a lot of people out there who made their car as a home.
Watch for videos on youtube.

Good Luck and hope this helps you out and stay safe.
Don't forget to share your experiences.